# Entered USA on VWP; want to visit Canada, then return

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, canada, us-visa-waiver-program, irish-citizens

I'm an Irish citizen visiting the US on the Visa Waiver Program. I have been on the east coast of the US for the summer traveling and sightseeing.

On the first of August I plan on going to Canada to travel around there for a while. My flight home to Ireland is from the US and I want to go and see the Mayweather and Mcgregor fight on the 26th of August in Vegas.

Is it possible for me to return to the US as my 90 day VWP entry expires on the 24th of August?

Comment: Welcome to the site! I edited your post to fix the confusion between VWP and ESTA (VWP is what lets you into the US without a visa; ESTA is a security clearance to get on the plane). I guessed that you're an Irish citizen -- could you correct that if you're not? It might make a difference to the answer.

Comment: Please let us know how it went (the immigration, not the fight).

Comment: The least ambiguous approach is to reenter the US on the 25th.

Answer (score 3):

There is no official rule preventing you from doing this, but for non-residents of Canada, the VWP clock continues while you're there in order to prevent visa runs.

However, given how long you'll be in Canada for, it should not be a problem to re-enter if you can present a confirmation of the return flight as well as paperwork proving you'll attend the Mayweather and McGregor fights. You may not be given a full 90-day period of stay though.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe? I got a new 90 days having only been in Canada for four. But I didn't need it (my journey was New York - Niagara Falls NY - Toronto - Chicago - Long Beach - San Francisco, over a period a bit over two weeks). I guess if you *need* it they might be more sceptical.

I did actually have drama re-entering the US at Toronto Airport. The computer was fine, and (I think) was the one to give me the new 90 days. My original entry stamp at JFK was wrong though (the wrong year). I even asked the CBP people at JFK baggage claim and they told me not to worry. Maybe I should have insisted.

By the book, re-entry from Canada should not give a new 90 days. It MIGHT (and did in my case). Do NOT rely on that.

If https://i94.cbp.dhs.gov/I94/ shows your exit from Canada, and especially if you re-enter the US by air and use an Automated Passport Control machine, you MIGHT get a new 90 days (as I did). No promises.

Comment: I gave a personal experience answer (I got a new 90 days at Toronto Airport preclearance having left the US at Rainbow Bridge) to say that is POSSIBLE to get a new 90 days. But you are not supposed to get that.

Comment: If you ARE going to try this, I suggest re-entering by air and using the machines. It also might help if Canada really exited you (check on https://i94.cbp.dhs.gov/I94/).

Comment: "you are not supposed to get that": the regulation actually says "may" be readmitted for the balance, which seems to leave it to the officer's discretion (or error) to grant a new 90 days.  But maybe you got the full 90 days because your prior admission appeared to be more than a year old?

Comment: Mine was about a WEEK old. Plus the COMPUTER had given the new 90 days, not an officer. (I used the APC machine at Toronto.) I think because at Rainbow Bridge I was exited (this is in my I-94 record, or at least was, it might have been purged) so when at Toronto preclearance I was given a full new entry.

Comment: I can't edit my earlier comment but I want to add this.

I don't think this would have applied if I had reentered from Windsor or elsewhere on land. I think they would have strictly applied the 90 days from JFK had I re-entered on land. I re-entered by air for two reasons - (a) reusing my ESTA and (b) the flight was just over £100, so it was not worth trying to go by bus or train.

Comment: Right, it was a week old, but perhaps the computer record showed the same incorrect year as the incorrect stamp in your passport and therefore showed it to be 53 weeks old.  Since the computer didn't know the date was incorrect, the computer treated your entry as a new entry with a fresh 90-day period.

Comment: No, I checked later on "My I-94" and the dates in the system were correct. Maybe it was BECAUSE I was fully exited, or re-entered by air, that it was deemed a fresh new entry?

Also, the *entry* date stamped in was correct, it was the *expiry* date that was a year wrong.

Comment: So your stamp showed that you had to leave nine months after your admission?  That's probably more likely, actually, as errors go.  Regardless, there's no law that _requires_ you to be admitted for the balance of your first period of admission when reentering after a short trip to Canada (or Mexico or adjacent islands), so the statement "re-entry from Canada should not give a new 90 days" is stronger than it needs to be.  It is always within the officer's discretion (subject to agency policy) to give a new period of admission. I have no idea how the computers are programmed.